# Simple displaying of second window: OS X & Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I'm trying to find how to bring up a second view/window after pushing a button on my primary window.  I have read about segues and I can get the first window to display the second but the second is not connected to a view controller so I can't add any code to any controls on the second view.  Try as I might I cannot create a SecondViewController.swift file and connect it to a window controller or a view controller.  The tutorials I have found all deal with iOS and I want OS X which means there are just enough differences to keep me from figuring this out.

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Ta,
A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make new file like:
[image]

After that, put these codes in your classes and that should do it.

```
class SecondWindowController: NSWindowController {

    convenience init() {
        self.init(windowNibName: "SecondWindowController")
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    private var secondWindowController: SecondWindowController?

    @IBAction func showSecondWindow(sender: AnyObject) {
        if secondWindowController == nil {
            secondWindowController = SecondWindowController()
        }
        secondWindowController?.showWindow(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prontto but no luck.  I suspect it's because I've got code in the wrong places.  I've got the original Main.storyboard and the ViewController.swift that goes with it and the SecondWindowController.xib and the SecondWindowController.swift that goes with that.  I'm not clear if the code classes you have given me go in each of the two controllers or both in the main view controller.  Can you show me your ViewController.swift and your SecondWindowController.swift?

Comment: They are in different files, but in that example it just looks they are in same file, but they're not, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Got it figured out.  Thanks Prontto.